# Logback-core UnknownHostException in catalina.out

Tags: tomcat7, logback

I have problem with logback-core. 
My project using apache-tomcat 7 webserver, 
and this is a JSF project.
The server starts with this error message in the catalina.out, 
but the instance and the webapps works well.
The logback-core-1.1.2.jar is in the $CATALINA_HOME/lib folder. 
This is the appropriate path for this jar file?
What does this error mean? Any possible solutions?

Thank you!

> The error message from **catalina.out**

```
-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.util.ContextUtil@17a1869 - Failed to get local hostname java.net.UnknownHostException
    at java.net.UnknownHostException
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.ContextUtil.getLocalAddressAsString(ContextUtil.java:59)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.ContextUtil.getLocalHostName(ContextUtil.java:41)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.ContextUtil.addHostNameAsProperty(ContextUtil.java:74)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction.begin(ConfigurationAction.java:57)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callBeginAction(Interpreter.java:275)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:147)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:129)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:50)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:149)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:135)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:99)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:49)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:148)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:107)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:295)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
    at  at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.<clinit>(AtmosphereServlet.java:172)
    at  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:143)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5198)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5481)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1074)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1858)
    at  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

> **logback.xml** from $CATALINA_HOME/conf folder

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level {%thread} [%logger{20}] : %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE-CATALINA" class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level {%thread} [%logger{40}] : %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/catalina-%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern> 
        <maxHistory>60<!-- days --></maxHistory>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize> 
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE-LOCALHOST" class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.base}/logs/localhost.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger{0} {%thread} %level : %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/localhost-%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern> 
        <maxHistory>60<!-- days --></maxHistory>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize> 
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE-MANAGER" class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.base}/logs/manager.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger{0} {%thread} %level : %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/manager-%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern> 
        <maxHistory>60<!-- days --></maxHistory>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize> 
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE-HOST-MANAGER" class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.base}/logs/host-manager.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger{0} {%thread} %level : %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/host-manager-%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern> 
        <maxHistory>60<!-- days --></maxHistory>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize> 
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<appender name="PROJECT" class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.base}/project.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger{0} {%thread} %level : %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/host-manager-%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern> 
        <maxHistory>60<!-- days --></maxHistory>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize> 
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>


<logger name="org.apache.catalina" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-CATALINA" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost]" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-LOCALHOST" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager]" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-MANAGER" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager]" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-HOST-MANAGER" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.project" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="PROJECT" />
</logger>


<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
```

Comment: post your logback.xml

Comment: I added the logback.xml to the post

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of library version mis match of logback-classic & logback-core, I have faced similar issue in tomcat 8, inside my project I have added logback-classic-1.1.7.jar and compile dependencies for the same is logback-core-1.1.7.jar which was not included but while deploying build tool used to download latest stable version of logback-core which was causing issue.
I fixed this by defining same version of logback-classic and logback-core.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error. :( Sorry

But what happens when you use this?

```
<configuration>
    <contextName>test</contextName>

    <appender
        name="console"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%level %logger{55} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger
        name="com.yourcompany"
        level="debug" />

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

If this works, I would start systematically adding stanzas from your logback to this one until you find the problem. Good luck!